# problems with setuptools while setting up trac on remote system without internet connection

Tags: trac, setuptools

I am trying to set up trac on a remote system running Fedora 12 that doesn't have an internet connection. So, I am copying all files from my system with the internet connection to that system and trying to install from source on that system.

When I run

```
 python ./setup.py install
```

I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./setup.py", line 17, in <module>
   from setuptools import setup, find_packages
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

I tried installing setuptools from source. I downloaded setuptools-0.6c11-1.src.rpm and ran

```
rpm -i setuptools-0.6c11-1.src.rpm
```

but I get the following warnings and nothing seems to happen:

```
warning: user pje does not exist - using root
warning: group pje does not exist - using root
warning: user pje does not exist - using root
warning: group pje does not exist - using root
```

How do I proceed?

Comment: Is 'pje' your user account name on the system you're copying from (that is, the one with the Internet connection)?

Comment: No. I wonder why it says that.